# Highlight Active Class in Navigation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying multiple solutions for this, but I have not been able to get this to work.

I'm currently using a Coda-type slider to propagate the content on my website using the following navigation:

```
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li id="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="work"><a href="#work-showcase">Work Showcase</a></li>
                    <li id="offerings"><a href="#brand-offerings">Offerings</a></li>
                    <li id="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li id="reason"><a href="#wow-factor">Reason to Believe</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
```

I have a few pages on my website that fall outside of the slider content.  I would like to be able to when on one of these "non-slider" pages -- to be able to click on one of the slider options at the top -- and have that content slide's navigation option highlighted with the .active or in my case ".there" class.

For example -- If I am on -- /packaged-brand-solutions.php (non-slider)  and I click on: Work Showcase (/index.php#work-showcase) -- not only does that area of the slider load -- but its accompanying navigation option is highlighted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The URL you provided doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm sorry -- those were just examples.  I changed the content.

Answer (score 3):

If I got your question right, something along these lines should work for you:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    $('.there').removeClass('there'); // reset the previously active nav item
    $(document.location.hash).addClass('there');
});
```

This is assuming that your `<li>` needs to get the `.there` class. If you want the `<a>` to get it, use this instead:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    $('.there').removeClass('there'); // reset the previously active nav item
    $('a', document.location.hash).addClass('there');
});
```

**Edit:**

I just realized that your link's hashes don't necessarily match your `<li>` element IDs. Here's the appropriate solution for this scenario:

```
// assuming that you want the <a> to get the .there class
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    $('.there').removeClass('there'); // reset the previously active nav item
    $('a[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]').addClass('there');
});

// assuming that you want the <li> to get the .there class
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    $('.there').removeClass('there'); // reset the previously active nav item
    $('a[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]').closest('li').addClass('there');
});
```

You might want to consider renaming your IDs, though ;)

**Edit 2, for the curious:**

I had initially written the selector like this, which is obviously moronic:

```
$('#' + document.location.hash.replace('#',''))
```

**Edit 3:** Michael, I can't get my head around as to why the above isn't working - you might wanna try this approach, though:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function(){
    $('.there').removeClass('there');
    $(this).addClass('there');
});
```

Comment: I posted an answer to this, but yours seems a lot more efficient and on-point. SHAME DELETED.

Comment: @DocileWalnut that's a pity. Please consider undeleting (and possibly explaining why it's less efficient) – it's always interesting to see alternative approaches; even if they may be less suited for the situation in question, they may come in handy othertimes.

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies.  vzwick, I added your edited solution that added the .there class to the <a> -- so... <li><a class="there">Link</a>

with no luck.

Comment: @MichaelHarmon That's pretty weird. Does the hash in your location bar change? (i.e. `yourdomain.com/foo#brand-offerings`) when you click on one of the links?

Comment: This is an example of the link that it loads when clicking on a link back to the slider: 

http://209.142.68.100/index.php#work-showcase

Comment: No reload, right? I assume you've wrapped the jQuery into a `$(document).ready(function(){ … });` block, right?

Comment: `document.location.hash` gives you the part `#work-showcase` only, no matter what else is in the location.

Comment: I have it like this:

        $(document).ready(function() {
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    $('.there').removeClass('there'); // reset the previously active nav item
    $('a[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]').addClass('there');
});

Comment: vzwick, any more ideas on this?

Comment: vzwick, would it help if I sent you a link to the actual project so you can see your script in there?  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: this is really awesome techniques , for this wrote lots of for loops, Good one.